# in syncfusion_flutter_calendar how can I customize CalendarElement.calendarCell?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using syncfusion_flutter_calendar package, and when its set on CalendarView.day, how can I customize empty day/time cell, for example how to change background color or border style and so on ?
to customize appointments it is quite easy but cant figure out how to customize empty cells.

I tried to customize it with basic SfCalendar properties, but couldn't find it.

[you can see image here, what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGOWd.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is not what I wanted but fixed it with these 2 properties :
SfCalendar(
specialRegions: ...... ,
timeRegionBuilder: ....... ,
)